# I can't use a form I added with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append a form (with a submit input). The problem is the submit input doesn't work after I added it...

Thank you in advance !

```
Here is when I add it :
$('div.message_holder').append('<div class="mesMessages">' + 
'<b style="color: #000">' + 
msg.username + '</b><br>' + msg.message +
'<form action="" method="POST" class="like">' +
'<input type="submit" id="like" value="Like"/>' + 
'</form>' + '</div>')

And here when I use it :
$( 'form.like' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
e.preventDefault()
socket.emit( 'likeEmission', {
username : "Joe",
like : "1"
})
```

Comment: Can you confirm your on('submit') event parenthesis are closing correctly? It seems that either it has an error or a typo mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit event is at the element level, set it to the document level

Change

```
$( 'form.like' ).on( 'submit', function(){})
```

To

```
$(document).on( 'submit', "form.like", function(){})
```

Additionally wrap the code in a `document.ready()` if you haven't already done so

Or another solution is to use the  `.bind()` method of jQuery
See ref: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: @Thunder69 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery method should be:

```
$('.like').submit(function);
```

Comment: the problem isn't the selector but rather the level at which the listener is attached